# Transferring data from two parties to one with PrepareForSegue Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, viewcontroller

I work with Xamarin.iOS I would like to use `PrepareForSegue` to transport data from variables from two `ViewControllers` to one, how should I do it?

I have already tried to change the value of the var variable that I use to transport data, change to another `ViewController`. It doesn't work, I don't know what to do, please help.

When I want to create a second `PrepareForSegue` method, I get an error no method found to be overridden.

Comment: Hi, could you show some code or image to explain more about your want.This will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not understanding

> from two ViewControllers to one

I will show how to transfer data from **ControllerA** to **ControllerB**.

ControllerA :

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);
    var controllerB = segue.DestinationViewController as ControllerB ;
    controllerB.passValue = "ControllerA's data";//set data from ControllerA
    controllerB.retSegue = segue;
}
```

ControllerB:

```
public string passValue;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    //labeltwo is a Label Control in ControllerB
    labeltwo.Text = passValue ; // here can get data from ControllerA
}
```

[image]

If your want is navigating from ControllerA to ControllerB ,and last to ControllerC, also can use up way to transfer data .